# Can I pay online if I first book with "pay at property" option?

Tags: bookings, booking.com, payment

I chose the "pay at property" option while booking a hotel room on [booking.com](https://www.booking.com/). Now I changed my decision to pay online, but couldn't find a way to do that.

On the "bookings" page, I see the following menu beside my booking.

[image: booking]

Isn't it possible to pay online hereafter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent a message to Booking.com customer service (via the "Get in touch" page) and their reply was approximately as follows.

> If you would like to withdraw the entire payment of the facility from
>   your credit card, please reply to this e-mail and send us your
>   request.
>
> Once we receive your prepayment request, we will share it with the
>   premises and, if deemed appropriate, will be withdrawn from your credit card.

I was expecting a self-driven way to pay online, but it seems that there is not without contacting the customer service or the hotel.

Comment: That is the way Booking.com always works. You give your payment details, the hotel uses them to get the money. It is always their action as far as I have seen so far. There might be other methods but I have not seen them at their site.

Comment: @Willeke I got it. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

I have had great success with calling booking.com customer service directly. I would suggest doing this as they will be the best party to answer your question. It is usually a long hold time but worth the wait to speak with someone personally.

Comment: I have had good results when using e-mail, but I did not have the same kind of question.

Comment: @Willeke, Leslie. Thanks for your suggestions. I posted the customer service's reply as an answer.